# Manage SharePoint OnLine Hub Navigation programmatically

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, csom

i've some sites that are registered as Hub site and i need to manipuate the hub navigation programmatically using c#. Is it possible? If so, how?

Thanks

Massimo Mattiello

Comment: Hi, did you check any of the share-point sources? This question is on the edge of suited for SO. See [ask].

Comment: Hi, i checked over all posts or internet sites but i did not found nothing

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.